Wordpress Media Library can't see compressed images
I use the plugin to convert jpg/png to Webp like Webp Express.
But the Media Library can't see compressed images.
It shows only original images.
How to make the Media Library show the compressed images?
https://prnt.sc/ZXWR2IClgxcf
https://prnt.sc/MxEO1wpWGHqV
https://prnt.sc/lnZvzOHzMb2T

What version of WordPress are you running? WordPress 5.8 added WebP support. If you have 5.8 or later you should be good.
